# Run .py when .txt is opened?

Tags: python, windows

This feels like a simple question, but I don't know if there's a simple answer. I basically just need to make a .py file run when I open up a .txt. I don't really want a loop to check and then run it, preferably i'd like to bundle the txt and the py so all the user sees is a .txt file. Thanks!

EDIT: More Specifically, is there some type of program that can bundle the txt and py so when they double click the txt it runs the py as well as opening the txt file?

Comment: Maybe visual basic will do the stuff. :P

Comment: What OS do you plan on doing this on?

Comment: @serk I plan on using window 8.1

Answer (score 1):

This is not as simple as it seems to be. For running a script when a file is *being opened* you somehow need to recognize the *open file* event, and I don't know if this would be possible, especially in Windows.

If you want to do something when the file *is being modified* (saved), you could give the [`watchdog`](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html#a-simple-example) package a try.

If this does not help, and you know what program is being used for opening the file, you could do it manually: Write a script which *first* does whatever you need to have done, *then* opens the text file using [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call).